# Tools to extract glyph data from bitmap font image

Tags: python, opengl, fonts, bitmap, gimp

I have all the characters of a font rendered in a PNG. I want to use the PNG for texture-mapped font rendering in OpenGL, but I need to extract the glyph information - character position and size, etc.

Are there any tools out there to assist in that process? Most tools I see generate the image file and glyph data together. I haven't found anything to help me extract from an existing image.

I use the gimp as my primary image editor, and I've considered writing a plugin to assist me in the process of identifying the bounding box for each character. I know python but haven't done any gimp plugins before, so that would be a chore. I'm hoping something already exists...

Comment: You'll have to generate it manually. For example, put borders (alpha value?) around each letter.

Comment: I expect to have to do this manually to some degree, but the right tool would make it easier. I'm thinking something that assists in marking the bounding box for each letter, then would spit out a text dump of the bounding info (x, y, width, height). I could then munge that into some other format for the final glyph info.

Comment: Are the characters separated by at least one row/column of “white” pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the way this works is you use a tool to generate the glyph images. That tool will also generate metric information for those glyphs (how big they are, etc). You shouldn't be analyzing the image to find the glyphs; you should have additional information alongside your glyphs that tell where they are, how big they should be, etc.

Consider the letter "i". Depending on the font, there will be some space to the left and right of it. Even if you have a tool that can identify the glyph "i", you would need to know how many pixels of space the font put to the left and right of the glyph. This is pretty much impossible to do accurately for all letters. Not without some very advanced computer vision algorithms. And since the tool that generated those glyphs already knew how much spacing they were supposed to get, you would be better off changing the tool to write the glyph info as well.

Comment: I didn't explain the problem well enough... regenerating the image with the glyph info is not an option - I only have the image. A fully-automated solution to extract the glyphs would be sweet, but that's way beyond what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jeremy Slade: You do realize that you can edit your question, right? So if you didn't explain it well enough, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to help you automate the process.

Assuming there is at least one row/column of *background* colour separating lines/characters, you can use the `Image.crop` method to check each row (and then each column of the row) if it contains only the *background* colour; thus you get the borders of each character.

Ping if you need further assistance.